# Normality of $\mathbb{R}^{J}$ when $J$ is uncountable

Tags: general-topology

I try to prove that $\mathbb{R}^{J}$ is not normal when $J$ is uncountable.

I read the proof in the answer of this question [If J is uncountable, then $R^J$ is not normal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787505/if-j-is-uncountable-then-rj-is-not-normal)

My question is that how can we assure that $B_{1}$ is properly contained in $B_2$?

Although $B_{2} \cup B_{1}$ gives $U(x_{2},B_{2} \cup B_{1}) \subseteq U(x_{2},B_{2}) \subseteq U $, if early constructed $B_{2}$ is contained in $B_{1}$, then it's just $B_{2} \cup B_{1} = B_{1}$, so that $n_{2} > n_{1}$ may not hold.

How can I assure that $B_{2}$ contains element which is not in $B_{1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a new answer to the question you linked to, in which I try to explain the strategy behind the proof given there.

There are two answers to your question:

- We don’t actually need $B_1$ to be properly contained in $B_2$ – in fact, we have more work to do if it is, because then we have to keep constructing the infinite sequence, whereas if $B_2=B_1$, we have a neighbourhood that imposes only injective constraints and thus immediately allows us to construct an element of $U\cap V$ (see the second paragraph of my answer to the other question, and the corresponding sentence later that starts with “Unless this process terminates”).
- If we did need $B_1$ to be properly contained in $B_2$, that wouldn’t be a problem either, since, as @ashpool’s answer to the other question notes, if $B_1\subseteq B_2$, then $U(x,B_2)\subseteq U(x,B_1)$ – so we can always add one more point to $B_2$ and the resulting neighbourhood would be smaller and still contained in $U$.